# como restar horas con el modulo time en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

basicamente, tengo que comparar dos horas distintas para determinar si es hora de ir a casa o en caso contrario determinar cuantas horas faltan hasta el tiempo de salida y pude hacer la comparación, pero no se como hacer la resta ya que son strings

Esto debe ser en modulo time ya que así lo pide el ejercicio y solo encuentro info con el modulo datetime

```
import pprint

ahora = time.strftime("%C")

if ahora > time.strftime("19:00") and ahora < time.strftime("08:00"):
   pprint.pprint("Es hora de ir a casa")
else:
   restante = time.strftime() - ahora
   pprint.pprint("El tiempo restante de trabajo es: ", restante)
```

PD: el pprint lo use para ver el directorio de comandos y quedara organizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿y la operaciónes y carga las tenes que hacer con cadenas? Eso lo complica mucho, no es lo mismo comparar cadenas que enteros en todo caso.
Si es posible usar enteros se podría hacer entre otras, de ésta forma:

```
#-*- coding: utf  -8 -*-
import pprint,time

ahora = time.strftime("%C")
```

lo correcto sería en todo caso

```
ahora = time.strftime("%H")
```

porque sino está obteniendo el siglo en lugar de la hora

en mi caso lo haría así, para que la hora sea un valor de entero:

```
ahora = time.localtime()[3]
```

como localtime devuelve una tupla obtengo solo el índice 3

```
if ahora > time.strptime("19:00"[:2],"%H")[3]  or ahora < time.strptime("08:00"[:2],"%H")[3]:
```

con strptime se convierte el valor de cadena a entero y solo uso los dos primeros valores de la cadena, por supuesto también lo devuelto por la función es una tupla, así que busco el índice específico.
Otra cosa no menos importante en tu código usas and y con esa lógica no se puede, no puede ser mayor y menor al mismo tiempo,debe ser uno u otro así que reemplazo el and por or

```
    pprint.pprint("Es hora de ir a casa")
else:
   restante = time.strptime("19:00"[:2],"%H")[3] - ahora
   pprint.pprint(f"El tiempo restante de trabajo es:  {restante} hora/s")
```

acá es basicamente lo mismo de lo explicado antes.

Sino te sirve porque deben ser solo cadenas, perdón.

Comment: no, no tiene que ser con strings, fue lo unico que encontre en google, me sirve mucho esta solucion, lo unico que no entiendo es lo de la tupla y el indice, mi suposicion es que localtime devuelve fecha y hora, entonces el indice 3 corresponderia al elemento de la hora, es correcto?

Comment: es como que localtime devuelve (año,mes,día,hora,minuto,etc), los índices permiten acceder a un lugar especiífico de tuplas,cadenas,listas. Te recomiendo que leas sobre slicing

Comment: Si la respuesta es tu solución no olvides marcarla como correcta :)